# How to use Apache Tika to extract the "Subject” field by using Apache Metadata class ?

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I'm trying to extract the "Subject" field from an email, but am having some trouble .  I was able to get the "To" and "From" fields already, like so :

```
String messageTo =  tikaMetadata.MESSAGE_TO;   //Works fine
String toField =  tikaMetadata.get(messageTo); //Works fine


System.out.println("From field is : " + fromField); //Works fine
System.out.println("To field is : "  + toField);    //Works fine


String messageSubj =  tikaMetadata.getValues("Message:Raw-Header:Subject"); 
String subjField =  tikaMetadata.get(messageTo); //Doesn't Work
```

How would we extract the subject field by using Tika ? 
any tips helpful thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try two ways:

1. `String subjectObs = tikaMetadata.get(tikaMetadata.SUBJECT);`
    but where`.SUBJECT` is deprecated
2. `String subject = tikaMetadata.get(TikaCoreProperties.DESCRIPTION);`probably the substitute that is closest to `Metadata.SUBJECT` (for more details about TikaCoreProperties look at this: [tika documentation](https://tika.apache.org/1.14/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/TikaCoreProperties.html))